# Prevent duplicate file in SharePoint

Tags: file, sharepoint, duplicates

We have would like to block duplicate entries being put into document library by team. Say one has already uploaded document, stop another team member from uploading it.
It there a simple javascript/CAML to prevent this if we put document library on a web page? This is for sharepoint online.

Comment: is it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to provide a custom page/form for document upload. Then before uploading just check if the document with same name already exists. if not then upload else not.
Out of box upload form also provide option to override existing file which might work for your case.